# Why G Does Not Light Up In Network Cable Tester?

Tags: networking, video, cable-tester

I have bought a network cable tester and in the manual it said that all lights from 1-8-G should light up in sequence. However I get only 8 without G, although the cable is in working condition.

Here is a picture of the manual:

[image]

**[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=9vihK_3qoM0&hd=1)**

The product's model is NS-468. If you have the same product, can you tell me what is wrong and what G is intended for?

Comment: G = ground => for STP (Shielded Twisted Pair) Most common use is unshielded.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your tester.
There are 8 strands in an unshielded network cable which is what you tested in your video.
A shielded cable also has a grounded metal sheath surrounding the 8 strands. The G on your tester refers to this.
I have a similar tester but in mine the shield is referred to as "Shield".

Comment: G refers to metal sheath? If so, why it does not blink?

Comment: The cable in your video doesn't appear to have one, it's unshielded.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, it is a perfectly valid cable type.

Comment: Oh i got it now. I was slow back then.

Comment: I was curious how the tester would even test this, since there's only 8 pins on the RJ45.  A shielded cable requires a connector with a metal wrap like this for the shield to connect with, and the tester in turn has a contact for the metal wrap on the connector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pju2u.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In my CHL-468 tester, the G position is not populated by an LED. I actually soldered in an LED and got it to work.